# How to select a TreeView node in WinAppDriver

Tags: c#, winappdriver

So I am trying to select a node on a TreeView using WinAppDriver, any thoughts on how to find a element that will have a value I can access the element with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TreeView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/treeview-overview) has TreeViewItems. The basic approach would be:

1. Get `driver.PageSource` property, save it to file and see generated xaml/xml file.
2. Use `driver.FindElementByXpath()` to search through xml (for name `Jesper Aaberg` from TreeView example xpath would be something like this: `//TreeView/TreeViewItem/TreeViewItem`)